# Overloaded methods in interface

Tags: c#, oop, interface, c#-3.0

my question for today: are overloaded methods in interface bad? You know, the "omit parameters if you don't care, we'll figure out the default values" kind of overloaded methods.
Like that:

```
void Add(object item); 
void Add(object item, bool shouldDoSomething); 
void Add(object item, bool shouldDoSomething, IUltraObscureDeviceContext context);
```

In this case I tend to think that only the latter belongs to an interface and others should be implemented in abstract class on top of it. But then again, I'm not sure.

Also, there are times when you just want different overloads doing slightly different work (stop me right there if overloaded methods should never be used for that). Or sometimes you can't just stuff nulls in place of some parameter, you want the exception thrown if something is null. Should I not use overloading in this case?

So basically I'm looking for some guidelines on overloaded methods in interfaces vs overloaded methods in abstract classes implementing these interfaces and so on.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If the contract that you're supplying promises to offer 3 versions of this method, then you should include those overloads.

Comment: Well, yeah, I know that, but the question kind of includes this too - should I supply contracts or not or sometimes or maybe

Comment: Why are we not using **default parameters**?

Comment: @Kirk Woll the trivial reason - .NET 3.5 still. Also, my question deals with other situations when default parameters won't cut it

Comment: @Kirk: Six of one, half a dozen.  The real question is whether they should be defaulted **in the interface**, not how those defaults are expressed.

Comment: @Jeffrey, I disagree.  It's precisely in the interface where it does the most good -- relieving consumers of implementing all those spurious overloads.

Comment: @Kirk:  Because default parameters aren't some magic bullet that now means overloads are obsolete.  For example, defaults must be constant, and perhaps the overload will pass a variable to the second or third overload.  Just because you have a shiny new toy doesn't mean it's a good idea to use it everywhere.

Comment: @all default enthousiasts: http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/ernow/archive/2010/04/03/default-but-what-default.aspx

Comment: @Ed Swangren, give me a concrete example where `null` will not suffice.  If the value is null, you can reassign the null value to whatever "variable" you would have passed in.  And the interface remains clean and uncluttered.

Comment: @Erno, I find that blog post utterly unpersuasive

Comment: @Kirk Woll: I never meant to convince. I only wanted to show that default parameters might not work the way you'd expect them.

Comment: @Erno: but then again, any feature might not work the way you'd expect it to if you don't bother reading specs

Comment: @Stook: A blunt estimation: if everyone read the specs, stackoverflow could drop more than half of its servers, disks and bandwidth.

Comment: @Kirk: Well, null will not suffice when... null will not suffice.  Never encountered and ArgumentNullException?  My point is that overloads and default parameters are not identical idioms and you can't just go and replace all of your overloads with default parameters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the defaults depend on the receiver of the method call, declare them as interface methods.

If the defaults are just defaults irrespective of the receiver, create the various reduced-argument-list overloads as extension methods and save implementors the headache of having to supply all the overloads themselves.

If you're dealing with some sort of nitty-gritty 80/20 rule exceptions, where implementation-independent defaults are *almost but not quite* always sufficient, you have a few options, none of which are that good:

- Deal with it as if they're always different, declare them as interface methods, and reimplement them everywhere.  Not very DRY.
- Deal with it as if they're always different, declare them as interface methods, and inherit a base class that provides the 80% default implementation.  Kind of clumsy, and not good if your sole base-class slot is already occupied.
- Create another interface containing those specific methods.  Declare extension methods with matching signature against the original interface.  In the extension methods, `as`-cast the `this` argument to the new interface type, and if it matches, call it there, otherwise fill in stock defaults.  Very funky, reliant on dynamic casting so not that great in an inner loop, but it decouples the defaults from both implementor and caller without sacrificing flexibility for implementors that can't take the "default defaults".

Comment: The last option is indeed very funky, but sounds like a good solution for a bad problem. Solid answer overall, thanks.

Comment: How about having the interface include a bitmask-enum parameter which indicates which of the other parameters are specified, and have implementation-independent wrappers call the "real" routine with proper values in the extra parameter?  If I had my druthers, there'd be a way to do that automatically, but even without an automated mechanism it could still be a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

Overloaded methods in an interface maybe Ok if the design of the interface warrants it. I've personally never needed to do this.

I wouldn't define default parameters values in an interface. That is an implementation detail that implementing classes that choose to surface.

you comment about having different implementations for the overloads....

Don't do that. Think of implementation of these overloaded methods as calling the one method that has all of the parameters defined with some default values. That's how users of your code would expect things to be.

If you need different behavior then use polymorphism. That's what its there for.

Comment: Polymorphism won't give you two implementations in one instance. I guess, that's what methods with different names are there for

Comment: Yes, indirectly what I was saying it that the implementing class should be different and not to mix things up by having different overloads implement things different, but to use polymorphism instead.

Answer (score 0):

IMO if the interface/contract spells it out, there should be no problem. However the goal is to simplify things when exposing an interface and hide the details. And thats where optional params come in handy.Pefectly object oriented languages like Python do not even have overloading AFAIK

Comment: Other perfectly adequate object-oriented languages like Objective-C don't have interfaces (ObjC has protocols which are somewhat related) which would also moot the question.